# Getting author id

Tags: php, wordpress

Im having some problems getting the author id inside of a archive page.
I need to get the author id so i can then get the rest of the data.

I tried a lot of codes i found online inside and outside the loop.
Everytime i only get the author id of the page where the archive is running from.

Here is a piece of the code i added to the template of the theme.

```
// Dealer Info
                                                        
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$dealer_name = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'dealer_name', true );
$office_phone = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'office_phone', true );

$dealer_address = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'dealer_address', true );
$dealer_address_latitude = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'dealer_address_latitude', true );
$dealer_address_longitude = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'dealer_address_longitude', true );

if( empty($dealer_name)) {
$user = get_userdata( $author_id ); 
$dealer_name = $user->user_nicename;
}
```

a few lines beneath:

```
<div class="dealer-informatie">
<h4 class="dealer-titel"><?php echo $vehicle_location_name; ?></h4>
    authorid of post: <?php echo $author_id; ?><br>
    Telefoon: <?php echo $vehicle_location_phone; ?><br>
    E-mail: <?php echo $vehicle_location_email; ?><br>
    Adres: <?php echo $vehicle_location_address; ?>
</div>
```

I tried this and a lot of other things without result:

```
global $post;
$author_id = $post->post_author;
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Start by inspecting the result of `var_dump(get_the_author_meta('ID'))` inside of a true WordPress loop. Does it return the User's ID correctly? If it doesn't, you have a problem elsewhere. If it does return what you expect, move on to inspecting `var_dump(get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID')))`. When called without additional parameters it will give you all meta data for that user. Do you see the key that you are looking for in there?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply,

When i add `var_dump(get_the_author_meta('ID'))` in the loop (single-vehicle.php) i get the user id belonging to the post.

when i add `var_dump(get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID')))` to the same single-vehicle.php i get a lot of data that belongs to the right author belonging to the post.

But when i try to replicate this in the archive page (autoroyal-cars.php) it is only showing the author of that page and not the authors of the posts.

Comment: "When I try to replicate this" - I'm not exactly sure what you mean. That code works inside of the loop only. If you move it outside of the loop, you need to give it more information about which thing you want the information about. So are you using it outside of the loop, and if so, where?

Comment: Thanks again for youre reply, i tried to be as clear as possible, but the lack of php knowledge, and english not being my native language, it can sometimes be hard ;).

Comment: The archive page itself is not in the loop, rather, the loop _can be_ and is _almost always_ used inside of that page template somewhere. Normally there is a literal and obvious "while (have_posts())` block somewhere, and everything inside is "the loop". There are other ways to create a true WordPress loop, to, so it sometimes depends. Can you show your loop code, or whatever you are doing to iterate?

Comment: This is the complete code of the page.
[link] https://pastebin.com/Wh2nVv64

From line 831 i added some code

Answer (score 1):

Okay, based on your last comment you have a custom query so you just need to setup the loop a little more explicitly:

```
// Your code, I just combined them into a single line
// You'll notice that `$cars` is gone that shouldn't be needed anymore
$cars_query = new WP_Query($search_args);

// See if we have anything
if ( $cars_query ->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $cars_query->have_posts() ) {

        // This sets up the global state so that "the loop" works
        $cars_query->the_post();

        // Your code goes here, and you will be inside of the loop at this point
        $car = get_post();
    }
 
} else {
    echo 'No cars found';
}

// Always a good idea when using custom queries
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, the above code replaced your previous `for` loop. So previously you had `if ( ! $cars ) :` and in the new code it is `if ( $cars_query ->have_posts() )`. Similarly, you previously had `foreach ( $cars as $car )` and the new code has `while ( $cars_query->have_posts() )`.

That should be the only things you need to update, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks i tried to add the code, but then i get the following:
Notice
`: Undefined variable: cars in
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/autoroyal-child/autoroyal/autoroyal-cars.php
on line 284` 

Its getting late now so i will try some more tommorow. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: @user2958073, I updated my answer with hopefully some clarification

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. i start to understand things better now!
I changed the code, and now i get the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/autoroyal-child/autoroyal/autoroyal-cars.php on line 269`

when i remove the `<?php else : ?>` part. i get the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/autoroyal-child/autoroyal/autoroyal-cars.php on line 874`

this is my code now: https://pastebin.com/rY9VAF8j

Comment: Yep, in my code I’m using braces, but in your code you are using the alternative syntax with semicolons and colons. They do the same, no right or wrong, you just need to match things up. So where your code has `endforeach`, my version just has `}`.

Comment: sorry for my late reply, i only find time to look at it again today. 

I don't know what im doing wrong. but now i get the following error:
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 148901888 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5275`

my current code is this:
https://pastebin.com/VbeJRzUi

Thanks again for al your help explaining so far. I think im almost there ;).

Comment: For this kind of stuff you often need to just put `die(“here”);` at various spots in your code to figure out which line is actually causing that general error. For instance, put it on 150. If you see “here” in your browser, put it after the WP_Query on the next line. If you see the memory error, it is the previous line that we need to investigate. Otherwise, work your way down, 50 lines at a time, and when you see the memory error, go more granular until you can isolate the specific one that is causing the problem.

Comment: Alright i did some testing. when i put `die(“here”);` on line 73 it shows here in the browser. when i put it on line 75 it is showing the memory error.

So the line were the error is starting is: 
`if( !empty($cars_type) AND $cars_type == "featured" ) {`

Thank you for showing me the way to how to find the error. Do you have any idea what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Hmm... that's a weird one. Are you sure it isn't _after_ the `apply_filters` call inside of the `if`? That's one that I could see potentially drawing more memory, the `if` itself doesn't really do anything expensive.

Comment: Hi Chris, i just double checked.
`Line: 73 if( !empty($cars_type) AND $cars_type == "featured" ) {
Line: 74 die(“here”);` is showing the memory error.

When i place the  `die(“here”)` above this line it is showing in the browser..

Comment: Would it help if i share some wp-admin credentials with you? maybe it is a quick fix for you? otherwise i will try to get some help local ;). thanks for al your explaining so far..

Comment: I'm sorry, unfortunately my day job is taking more time than normal, so it might be better to ask someone locally. Good luck with this!

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping me so far!. when i find the solution i will share it here..